# Child Constraint Not Working

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging, constraints, parent

I applied the child constraint on the eye to follow the movement of the face but it doesn't work properly. As you can see the picture, when I played the video, the eye doesn't follow the face. Is there any way the eye can be parented properly without joining them?[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have chosen the character object as *Target* of your *Child Of* constraint but as your character is moved by an armature, the constraint won't make the eye follow the object, you need to parent to the armature's head bone instead.